# Ghostscript PDF optimization causes memory issues

Tags: pdf, optimization, out-of-memory, ghostscript

I am running ghostscript (Ghostscript 9.54.0 (2021-03-30), Arch Linux) on a ~200mb file with 270 pages like this:

```sh
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -sOUTPUTFILE=out.pdf input.pdf
```

But ghostscript's memory usage is ballooning very fast, reaching over 32gb and crashing my machine.

Is this behaviour to be expected? It seems really excessive.

Comment: It really depends on the input file, but it does seem excessive. You could open a bug https://bugs.ghostscript.com/ and one of could investigate it when time permits.

Comment: The input file is a scanned book (meaning: a lot of background images) with OCR.

Comment: I added a bug report: https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=704142